# Cypress SSO Azure without Client_secret

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, cypress, microsoft-dynamics

I'm struggling to solve an issue that I got on trying to login via Single Sign On from Microsoft Azure using Cypress. It is possible to do it without using the Client_Secret? How can I do it?

I've been spending more than a week trying to solve this situation...

I'm a junior on this, so if you could help-me I would be very grateful.

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Any update this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Navigate to your AD App in the portal -> `Authentication` -> set `Allow public client flows` to `Yes` like below.

[image]

Then in the [blog](https://xebia.com/blog/how-to-use-azure-ad-single-sign-on-with-cypress/), in step `Cypress utility for mimicking react-adal`, it uses the [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow), there is a comment post by @Bryce Kolton under the blog, he uses the [ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc), in this flow, you could use it without `Client_Secret` via a public client App as you changed above(Allow public client flows), just refer to it.

```
/* eslint-disable no-underscore-dangle */
import { AuthenticationContext } from ‘react-adal’;
import { azTenantId, azClientId } from ‘../../server/config/environment’;

// Need to get data points from server’s environment, not src
const adalConfig = {
tenant: azTenantId,
clientId: azClientId,
cacheLocation: ‘localStorage’,
replyUrl: ‘/’,
endpoints: {
api: ”,
},
};
const authContext = new AuthenticationContext(adalConfig);

export default async function doLogin() {
// getCachedToken also does an expiration check so we know for sure the tokens are usable
if (
!authContext.getCachedToken(adalConfig.endpoints.api)
|| !authContext.getCachedToken(adalConfig.clientId)
) {
const response = await cy.request({
method: ‘POST’,
url:
‘https://login.microsoftonline.com/mercedesme.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token’,
// qs: { ‘api-version’: ‘1.0’ }, // uncomment if your consuming resource expects the ‘aud’ to have a prefix of ‘sn:’
headers: {
‘cache-control’: ‘no-cache’,
‘content-type’:
‘multipart/form-data; boundary=—-WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW’,
},
form: true,
body: {
grant_type: ‘password’,
response_type: ‘code’,
client_id: ‘[[yourappsclientid]]’,
username: ‘[[yourtestuzseremail]]’,
password: ‘[[yourtestuserpassword]]!’,
scope: ‘openid’,
resource: ‘[[some-resource-id]]’,
},
});
// Store the token and data in the location where adal expects it
authContext._saveItem(authContext.CONSTANTS.STORAGE.IDTOKEN, response.body.access_token);
authContext._saveItem(
authContext.CONSTANTS.STORAGE.ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY + adalConfig.endpoints.api,
response.body.access_token,
);
authContext._saveItem(
authContext.CONSTANTS.STORAGE.ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY + adalConfig.clientId,
response.body.access_token,
);
authContext._saveItem(
authContext.CONSTANTS.STORAGE.EXPIRATION_KEY + adalConfig.endpoints.api,
response.body.expires_on,
);
authContext._saveItem(
authContext.CONSTANTS.STORAGE.EXPIRATION_KEY + adalConfig.clientId,
response.body.expires_on,
);
authContext._saveItem(
authContext.CONSTANTS.STORAGE.TOKEN_KEYS,
[adalConfig.clientId].join(authContext.CONSTANTS.RESOURCE_DELIMETER)
+ authContext.CONSTANTS.RESOURCE_DELIMETER,
);
}
}
```

To use the ROPC flow successfully, make sure your scenario meets the requirements below, e.g. your user account is not MAF-enabled.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @JoyWang. The problem is that I'm not owner of the application. It's a 3th party application and I really need to test it.